# Why a web page for Google App Indexing

Tags: android-app-indexing

I'm trying to understand what the purpose is of requiring you to have your own web page when you tie it to content in your own app in order for Google App Indexing to work. If a person is performing a Google Search on keywords using their mobile browser (Chrome), I can understand how it would be possible for Google to include links to the app's activities that are relevant to search results that match the content in your app, but why is having your own web page necessary. I don't see the reason for this. Many app developers create apps that don't have websites yet provide content that theoretically can be indexed and found when someone does a Google Search. After all, an app providing content that can be indexed should be treated no differently than any website that can be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of Google App Indexing in 2013, it was mandatory to have your own website because it was through your website that Google would discover your deep links and proceed to validate them against your app content. The deep links were discovered through your website:app association, on-page markup or sitemap.

Currently there are other options on how to publicize your deep links and it is also possible to index your app-only content as stated in this release - http://insidesearch.blogspot.ie/2015/11/new-ways-to-find-and-stream-app-content.html

However, the app-only content indexing is still in development stages so is not available for everyone. You can still manifest your interest in participating by filling out this form - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/app-only

You can find more information regarding Google App Indexing in their online documentation. It was updated recently.

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/introduction

Hope you find this helpful.